# Factors variables labels coded according number of levels

Tags: r

I'd like to get a R script to count/identificates factors variables levels  and recode labels according this number of levels.

I have a dataframe whith several factor variable. They are coded from "A" to "E" , "A" to "H" or "A" to "D" etc, for example. I want recode to 1:5 , 1:8 , 1:4 etc labels automatically, with one command. I don't want recode label for each one manually.

I saw a way with this command:
nums_fct <- factor(nums, lebels = levels, ordered = T), but this would be for each variable, just what I don't want.

I'm a Stata user in learning R process.I appreciate the help.

Comment: Fyi. If you post a [MCVE] you are more likely to get tested code. My answer below is not tested. It’s *your* responsibility.

Comment: IRTFM,
Great!
This code works.
Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

This is the reverse of the usual request to convert character digits to type numeric.

```
dfrm2  <- dfrm # make copy
dfrm2[ sapply(dfrm2, is.factor) ] <-  # only work on factors, preserve structure of dfrm2
        lapply( dfrm2[sapply(dfrm2, is.factor)],  #
            function(x) { as.character( as.numeric( x)) } )
```

Comment: @AnnaPaulaGonçalves : there is a `levels<-` function that will let you reassign the character values of levels. If you need a coded example you should use ‘dput` to deliver an unambiguous data object. DO NOT DO THIS IN COMMENTS. Use [edit] facilities to add to you question body.